# Google Place API usage limitations and billing(2019)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-places-api, google-places, google-place-picker

After the deprecation of `google place picker` I have to custom made it.I have to use google places API. 
Let's say I have estimated hit of 1000/day for APIs like 
1. Place Search 
2. Place Autocomplete
-provided by place picker package.

The billing documentation is so complex I am unable to understand.
What I understood is:
a. Addition of billing account by adding credit Card is mandatory now
b. for Place Picker 150,000 hits/24 hours is free (after I exhaust the limit, what will happen? Will my app show error or I will be charged?)

I am new to this field. Can anyone help me by proving the required info. Thank You.Is there any alternate option also please mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/) is the pricing tab for Maps, Places & Routes.

If you have more detailed questions regarding costs it will be better idea to contact [Billing](https://cloud.google.com/contact/) department.

Comment: please describe me instead of giving some links.